# OpenCL: What to do when there is no compatible GPU?

Tags: opencl

I'm learning OpenCL and I have a compatible x86 CPU, but my GPU doesn't support OpenCL at all.
So when I call the clGetDevices API, it returns nothing.

As I'm just learning this framework and I'm not looking for optimization or higher performance, is it necessary to get a new system ? (While OpenCL programs are running on my platform)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It should be sufficient to have an OpenCL SDK that supports your system's CPU and/or GPU in order to learn OpenCL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.acooke.org/cute/Developing0.html describes how i worked with a cpu (only) a few years ago.  basically, the AMD OpenCL driver worked with my Intel CPU.

Comment: Intel and AMD both provide OpenCL implementations that can target a CPU, and NVidia might, too. Intel's implementation probably only works on their CPUs, but AMD's works on either vendor's CPUs (and can sometimes outperform Intel's implementation).

Comment: Intel's CPU driver works on any x86 that supports SSE4.2 (not just Intel CPUs).
AMD's CPU driver also works on other x86 chips.
NVIDIA does not make a x86 CPU driver.